# Makefile. How to exclude one particular file from compilation?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to exclude *main.cpp* file from the list of files to be compiled defined by the rule below:

```
$(TMPDIRPATH)%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
ifneq ($(notdir $<), main.cpp)
        @$(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
endif
```

This 'ifneq' condition always evaluates to true, which is bizarre. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to exlude one file from an explicit rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't the best way to do it, but if you do it along these lines, write it as a shell condition, not using GNU make conditionals:

```
$(TMPDIRPATH)%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
    @if [ $(notdir $<) != main.cpp ]; \
    then $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<; \
    fi
```

The continuation markers (backslashes) are needed.  So are the semicolons.  The values prefixed with `$` will be expanded by `make` before the shell is invoked to interpret them.  You probably don't want the echo where it is, either.  You probably need:

```
$(TMPDIRPATH)%.o: %.cpp
    @if [ $(notdir $<) != main.cpp ]; \
    then echo compile $<; \
         $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<; \
    fi
```

The way I would expect to do it is with a list of the files to be compiled.  Using any wild card mechanism leads to problems when extra files are added - other tests, or stray files that aren't really part of the system.

---

The comment says "But the GNU Make Manual says `ifneq` should work".

The `ifneq` would work if it were positioned correctly, which means 'not indented as part of the commands associated with a rule'.  You could, therefore, write something like (an appallingly bad example, but my brain's on the fritz):

```
ifneq (${CFLAGS}, -Wall)
CFLAGS += -Wall
endif

file1.o: file1.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

But when the `ifneq` is indented as in the question, it is just a command that actually isn't found on the system when the `make` runs the shell to process the command.

Comment: It works. But I am completely puzzled about `ifneq` business. It should work in accordance to the gnu make manual. Thanks for the tip as well. Unfortunately I don't know which files are relevant and can't specify them explicitly. It's not my project. Just trying to revitalize the build script that worked many moons ago. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @bioffe: I've tried to explain in the extra information in the answer.

Comment: I figured the indentation aspect and fixed it with in my code. It doesn't fail anymore, but evaluates always to True.  Just updated the question few minutes ago.

Comment: @bioffe: I believe the conditions are now evaluated as the file is read, rather than when the commands are executed.  So, as the file is read, the 'ifneq' evaluates to true.

Answer (score 14):

Why don't you try using the [`filter-out` text function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) if you're using GNU Make.

*Returns all whitespace-separated words in text that do not match any of the pattern words, removing the words that do match one or more. This is the exact opposite of the filter function.*

*For example, given:*

```
objects=main1.o foo.o main2.o bar.o
mains=main1.o main2.o
```

*the following generates a list which contains all the object files not in ‘mains’:*

```
$(filter-out $(mains),$(objects))
```

Comment: "Returns all whitespace-separated words in text that do not match any of the pattern words, removing the words that do match one or more." This is the cleanest answer - would be useful if you added the example on the linked site to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `ifneq` line is evaluated only once, when make starts up and parses the makefile. In that context, `$<` is empty.

To get different behavior for each of the targets matched by your pattern rule, you could do something like

```
$(TMPDIRPATH)%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
    @$(if $(filter main.cpp,$<),$(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<)
```

It might help you to think of the difference between `ifneq` and `$(if)` in a makefile as like the difference between `#if` and `if()` in C code.

Taking a step back, though: If you don't want `main.cpp` to be compiled by this rule, then you probably want to provide an explicit rule with `$(TMPDIRPATH)main.o` as its target, which will be preferred to the pattern rule always. Or, if you don't want`$(TMPDIRPATH)main.o` to get made *at all*, you should be looking for rules that have it on the right sight of the `:`, and removing it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Make doesn't really have a good way to handle conditionals within a rule. You could put the conditional in the command, but in this case there's a much cleaner way:

```
$(TMPDIRPATH)main.o:
    @echo compile $< (but not really)

$(TMPDIRPATH)%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
    @$(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't realize you didn't *have* a `main.cpp`. The solution is simple: remove `main.cpp` as the prerequisite of the `main.o` rule (I've removed it above). Now the makefile doesn't need it, and won't try to build it.

But you're still running the rule, which means that something is still trying to build `main.o`, as either an explicit target or a prerequisite of something else. That is a symptom of confusion, which this change to the makefile will not fix. If you tell us more about the situation, maybe we can propose a better solution. What calls for `main.o`? Do you have a `main.o`? What target do you specify when you call Make?

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `main.cpp', needed by `tmp/main.o'.  Stop.
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

Comment: I really don't know much about `Make`. It seems like this scripts wants to execute main.cpp right away. I fixed the rule with '$(TMPDIRPATH)main.o: %.cpp' but it doesn't handle main.cpp case anyway.